# CSS not works for anchor tag in Outlook mail

Tags: html, css, outlook-2007

CSS applied to link in Outlook not works

HTML:

```
<tr>
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="color:#FFF;height:40px;width:475px;display:block;"><td style="background-color:#000;height:40px;width:475px;">Click Me</td></a>
</tr>
```

it only display link to "Click Me" text not to all

Note: It should display link to all td i.e. width:475 & height:40

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: I think you are missing a opening "td" tag! :)

Comment: While the specs have changed for html5, it is a general convention to not enclose block elements (such as `<td>`) inside a link. Instead, flip the order of the tags around and use styling to define the width and height of the anchor.

Answer (score 14):

You can use outlook specific HTML to fix this

```
<div><!--[if mso]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" stroke="f" fillcolor="#556270">
<w:anchorlock/>
<center>
<![endif]-->
 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" style="background-color:#556270;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Show me the button!</a>
<!--[if mso]>
</center>
</v:rect>
<![endif]--></div>
```

Also refer http://buttons.cm/ for creating 'bulletproof' email buttons :)

Comment: This was literally the only thing that managed to get my styled links to show in Outlook, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<tr>
  <td style="background-color:#000;height:40px;width:475px;">
     <a href="http://www.google.com" style="color:#FFF;height:40px;width:475px;display:block;">Click Me</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem so I found this.
Just use border style with the same background color so your whole anchor link will clickable.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="background-color:#000;height:40px;width:475px; border:1px solid #000; color:#FFF;height:40px;width:475px;display:block;">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: its a nasty surprise took me an hour to figure it out.. some of the css on anchor tag only works when you add border..

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that the style should be applied to all the td ?

well if yes, what you have done wont work, what you've done is called an inline css style which will be applicable only for that particular element.

if you want it to be applied for all the td's then you'll have to have what is called the internal css style:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
td{
//your code here
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
//your code here
</body>
</html>
```

and by the way, your code nesting is not proper,

u have an opening 'a' tag and then an opening 'td' tag and then closing 'a' tag and then closing 'td' tag...

you must either have it as:

`<td><a></a></td>`
or
`<a><td></td></a>`

try:

```
<tr>
  <td style="background-color:#000;height:40px;width:475px;">
     <a href="http://www.google.com" style="color:#FFF;height:40px;width:475px;display:block;">Click Me</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem is that your link should be in your table cell:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#000;">
       <a href="http://www.google.com" style="color:#FFF;height:40px;width:475px;display:block;">Click Me</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd also check out Microsoft's guide for creating Outlook CSS and HTML support because there are a lot of gotchas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx.  In general avoid block elements and floats in favor of table layouts.  Also Outlook email only supports CSS1 specification.

Answer (score 0):

As  ProfileTwist indicated in a comment the hierarchy should be:

- `<tr><td><a href=link>text</a></td></tr>`

I see this is an old post, however contrary to other answers the intention was probably to make the table white (FFF) and the text black (000).

Answer (score 0):

use this for remove extra spacing issue on outlook

```html
<tr>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" style="font-size:0;display:block;">
    <td style="background-color:#000;height:50px;width:400x;">Click here</td>
    </a>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your anchor tag with a `span` tag and add styles to the span instead of `a` tag.

```html
<span style="color:#fff">
  <a href="#">
    Click Me
  </a>
</span>
```